# How to convert Word documents to PDF without formatting issues

Tags: asp.net, pdf, ms-word, aspose.words

I need to convert Word documents to PDF in a Django application. The user uploads a Word document template. The application should then do a mail merge based on data in the database and save the PDF.

The volume can be quite substantial - up to 50000 in a batch.

I've tried various libraries including Aspose and I found formatting issues with all of them. It just doesn't look the same compared to opening the real Microsoft Word and saving as a PDF.

It seems like my only option is to automate Microsoft Word from a .NET application.

Since my application runs on a Linux server, I would need to create a separate asp.net application with Word installed. The app then takes the word document as input and returns the PDF.

I'm confident I can get it to work, but it feels like a big hack and not sure how well it will handle 50000 PDFs. It seems like there should be better ways but I can't find it? I'm also wondering if this will create a licensing issue.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: "I've tried various libraries... " this sort of question should be asked here instead https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should note, to properly layout and render MS Word document to PDF or any other fixed page format (XPS, Image etc) the fonts used in the document are required. If Aspose.Words cannot find the required fonts, [the missed fonts are substituted according to substitution rules](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/manipulating-and-substitution-truetype-fonts/). Font substitution might affect document layout. You can implement [IWarningCallback](https://reference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/iwarningcallback/) to get a warning when font substitution is performed.

Since you are running conversion on Linux, most likely, MS fonts are not available there by default and you should [install the required fonts](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/installing-truetype-fonts-on-linux/). Alternatively, you can simply copy the required fonts into some folder and [specify true type fonts location](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/specifying-truetype-fonts-location/) in `FontSettings`. I believe installing the required fonts will resolve formatting issues on your side.